# react-calendar onChange TS2769: No overload matches this call Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-calendar

I used the response calendar library.

The default code suddenly gives an onChange prop error. What should I do? (It worked before.)

My code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Calendar from "react-calendar";

function App() {

    const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());

    return (
        <div>
            <Calendar
                onChange={onChange}
                value={value}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Error message

`TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: CalendarProps | Readonly<CalendarProps>): Calendar', gave the following error.     Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Date>>' is not assignable to type '(value: Value, event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.       Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.         Type 'Value' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.           Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: CalendarProps, context: any): Calendar', gave the following error.     Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Date>>' is not assignable to type '(value: Value, event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.`

I checked npm version, config files and re-install. But it still don't working.

Comment: can you provide a codesandbox ?

Comment: do you mean 
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/competent-sanderson-r0t9vz?welcome=true
??

Answer (score 3):

You are not providing the correct typing for value which is typed like :

```
type ValuePiece = Date | null;

export type Value = ValuePiece | [ValuePiece, ValuePiece];
```

so in order to fix this change your state type to :

```
type  ValuePiece = Date|null;
function App() {
  const [value, onChange] = useState<ValuePiece|[ValuePiece,ValuePiece]>(new Date());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Calendar value={value} onChange={onChange} selectRange={false}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you don't wanna work with types rename your file from App.tsx to App.js